# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user. Can't make a table for user

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my models.py where I made my User table.

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('PostIntmath', backref='author', lazy=True)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class PostIntmath(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

I don't see what is wrong.
I have made forms to take inputs for the username and email.

My routes.py seems fine as well but whenever I try to log in it gives me an error

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first() #error on this line
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

The error I get is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.image_file AS user_image_file, user.password AS user_password
FROM user
WHERE user.email = ?
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('abc456@gmail.com', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Please help me out. I am new to flask and SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the following 3 things:

1. Table is created with proper name.
2. Table imported from model to routes.py

   ```
   from app.models import User
   ```
3. Table name added in 'init' file or file having shell_content_processor. You should have following code present.

   ```
   from app import app, db
   from app.models import User

   @app.shell_context_processor
   def make_shell_context():
       return {'db': db, 'User': User}
   ```

   Change the name of app with your app name.

Comment: Thank you, but I fixed my issue by doing a db.drop_all() and db.create_all() in python the module.

Answer (score 0):

write this in your code:

```
@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
     db.create_all()
```